# Summernote custom button pass context and data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, summernote

I am using summernote in angular I want to create a custom button.

I would like to pass the listHit in customButton as parameter like this 'testBtn': this.customButton(context, listHit) but I am not sure how to do this since the function looks like this 'testBtn': this.customButton any help would be appreciated thank you.

My custom button looks something like this.

```
  customButton(context) {    
    
    var listHit = ['One', 'Two', 'Tree'];
    
    const ui = ($ as any).summernote.ui;
    var i;
    var listHitHtml = "";
    for (i = 0; i < listHit.length; i++) {
      listHitHtml += "<li>" + listHit[i] + "</li>";
    }


    var button = ui.buttonGroup([
      ui.button({
        className: 'dropdown-toggle',
        contents: '<i class="fa fa-comments"/><span class="caret"></span>',
        tooltip: '@erp_colombia.Lang.Resource.conAvailableComments',
        data: {
          toggle: 'dropdown'
        }
      }),
      ui.dropdown({
        className: 'drop-default summernote-list',
        contents: "<div id=\"container-comentario\"><div id=\"dialog\" title=\"Comentarios\" ><h1 class=\"header-comentario\">" + 'Comment' + "</h1><ul id=\"liste-comentarios\"><ul>" + listHitHtml + "</ul></div></div>",
        callback: function ($dropdown) {
          $dropdown.find('li').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
              context.invoke("editor.insertText", $(this).html() + "\n");
            });
          });
        }
      })
    ]);

    return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
  }
```

Here is my pdfmaker config

```
  this.config = {
    placeholder: placeholder,
    shortcuts: false,
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
    //tabsize: 2,
    hint: {
      mentions: this.quoteCommentsForSummerNote,
      match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
      search: function (keyword, callback) {
        callback($.grep(this.mentions, function (item: any) {
          return item.indexOf(keyword) == 0;
        }));
      },
      content: function (item) {
        return item;
      }
    },
    height: 200,
    toolbar: [
      ['myotherbutton', ['testBtn']],
    ],
    buttons: {
      'testBtn': this.customButton
    }
  }
```

And this is my angular html

Here you can fiddle with a example I created a list that we will assume comes from a service I would like to pass this list to customButton

```
  listStringFromDbService = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-gdvvbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I figured this out.

You can change your button declaration to a function that returns a button function. That way you can pass data to it before constructing the function that Evernote binds to `testBtn`.

Change the function declaration (expression or declaration will work, like you pointed out)

```
function customButtonGenerator(arr) {
  return function (context) {
    const ui = $.summernote.ui;
    const button = ui.button({
      contents: '<i class="note-icon-magic"></i> Hello',
      tooltip: 'Custom button',
      container: '.note-editor',
      className: 'note-btn',
      click: function () {
        context.invoke('editor.insertText', 'Hello from test btn!!! ' + arr);
      },
    });
    return button.render();
  };
};
```

then when you create the ui config you can generate the button function instead:

```
buttons: {
      testBtn: customButtonGenerator(this.listStringFromDbService),
    },
```

[Here's an updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-1knb2c?file=src/app/app.component.ts) showing a working example.

Comment: I could change it but for me the function customButton(context) works. My question is how to I pass a list of item to the customButton function? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I wildly misunderstood your question. What is this list ultimately supposed to do once the button knows about it?

Comment: I updated the answer assuming you'd like to pass the array into the invoke method on click, but this should be close to what you want even if you're doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the answer of MPawlak like this in it there is a dropdown where you can click the items you want to add. Also I have the passing of parameter to the custom button that still works. Thanks to MPawlak

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-summernote-demo-yq8t4t